# If the quotients of a zero-limit sequence are less than a constant, the quotients converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, numerical-methods

Suppose a sequence $|a_n|\to 0$ as $n$ approcheas infinity. Also suppose that $|a_{n+1}|\leq c*|a_{n}|$ for some constant $c$. Does this imply, that $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|$ converges?
I'm asking this question because of differing definitions for rate of convergence in my course and on Wikipedia.
For some sequence $s_n$ using $a_n:=|s_n-s|$, where $s$ is the limit of $s_n$,
(German) Wikipedia defines a sequence as converging with order $p$, if $a_n\leq c*a_{n+1}^p$, but we defined it as $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n^p}$ converges and as I'm now realising English Wikipedia uses the latter definition as well.
During my course this implication was used as obvious, but I'm not able to prove monotony of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ under the given conditions. The quotient sequence is obviously bounded per definition, so only a proof of monotony would be needed to prove convergence.

Comment: No, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$ can – for example – be equal to $\frac 12$ for even $n$ and equal to $\frac 13$ for odd $n$.

Comment: ok sorry i might have mistated my question. $a_n$ is meant to be the absolute value of something, let me change it. Then this wouldn't work with $a_n$ still being a zero-sequence would it?

Comment: That does not change anything.

Comment: You should also specify $a_n\neq 0$ else the quotient doesn't mean anything.  But, even so, it need not converge.

Comment: To make the example by @MartinR very explicit, set $a_1=1$, $a_{n+1}=\frac12a_n$ when $n>0$ is even, and $a_{n+1}=\frac13a_n$ when $n>0$ is odd. That is, $a=(1,1/3,1/6,1/18,1/36,1/108,1/216,\ldots)$. Then $\lvert a_n\rvert\to0$, $\lvert a_{n+1}\rvert\leq\frac12\lvert a_n\rvert$ for each integer $n>0$, and yet $\lvert a_{n+1}/a_n\rvert$ diverges.

Comment: So the different definitions for order of convergence are not equivalent then? (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence for the seconde case, https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konvergenzgeschwindigkeit for the first case, under "Konvergenz der Ordnung q" you can find it defined as the existence of a c, so that $|s_{n+1}-s|\leq c*|s_n-s|^q$